How to Classify Driving Behaviors (Acceleration, Braking, Turning) Using 2D Coordinates and Velocity?
I'm working on a project to classify driving behaviors based on a vehicle's position and velocity data. For each time step, I have the following information:
$x, y $ : Position coordinates in a 2D plane
$V_x, V_y$ : Velocity components along the $x$- and $y$-axes.
The goal is to classify the car's behavior at each time step into categories such as accelerating, braking, turning, or maintaining a steady speed.
Challenges:
One challenge is that analyzing just two consecutive points might not be enough to identify certain behaviors, such as turning. For instance, a turn could appear similar to braking if only speed changes are considered, but analyzing a larger window of points could reveal the change in direction. From what I gathered detecting turns is the more difficult part.
Approach:
I want to achieve this using a rule-based approach rather than machine learning. Since the dataset is relatively small and the time intervals between points are large (about 1 second), I think a simple set of rules could work effectively.
What I’m Looking For:

Suggestions for methods, algorithms, or concepts I should research for this type of classification.

Ideas for how to process the data to make classification more accurate (e.g., analyzing changes over multiple points, using position and velocity differences, etc.).


Since I'm not familiar with creating algorithms, any direction as to:

what to research - methods, algorithms, reading materials
suggestions to what metrics can or should be derived from the data (deltas and how to use them for example)

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this classification system. If you have relevant resources or reading materials to recommend, I’d be grateful to learn more. Thank you!

Welcome to DS.SE @Aaron
Classifying Driving Behaviours Using Position and Velocity Data
I would suggest a rule-based system for classifying driving behaviours (accelerating, braking, turning, and maintaining steady speed) using kinematic principles, curvature analysis, and temporal metrics. Following are some concrete ideas for doing this:

Key Concepts and Methods
Kinematics
Kinematics describes motion through position, velocity, and acceleration without considering forces. Essential relationships:

Position $\rightarrow$ Velocity $\rightarrow$ Acceleration.
Motion represented as vector components along $x$ and $y$ axes.

Curvature and Trajectory Analysis
Curvature quantifies the sharpness of a turn and can be computed as:
$$
k = \frac{|x'y'' - y'x''|}{(x'^2 + y'^2)^{3/2}}
$$
where $x', y'$ are velocity components (first derivatives), and $x'', y''$ are acceleration components (second derivatives).
Time-Series Analysis
Time-series methods are highly useful for analysing trends over multiple time points. For example, using:

Moving averages: Smooth noise in position/velocity data.
Rate of change analysis: Identify temporal trends over sliding windows.
ARCH-based models: When you have heteroskedasticity (fluctuating variance)


Metrics and Features to Derive
Speed
Compute speed as the magnitude of velocity:
$$
\text{Speed} = \sqrt{V_x^2 + V_y^2}
$$
Acceleration
Acceleration is the rate of change of speed:
$$
\text{Acceleration} = \frac{\Delta \text{Speed}}{\Delta t}
$$

Positive acceleration: Accelerating.
Negative acceleration: Braking.

Heading Change
Heading change quantifies directional shifts between consecutive velocity vectors:
$$
\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{\mathbf{v}_1 \cdot \mathbf{v}_2}{|\mathbf{v}_1| |\mathbf{v}_2|}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are velocity vectors at consecutive time steps.
Curvature
Measure turning sharpness using curvature:
$$
k = \frac{|x'y'' - y'x''|}{(x'^2 + y'^2)^{3/2}}
$$
Jerk
Jerk captures sudden changes in acceleration:
$$
\text{Jerk} = \frac{\Delta \text{Acceleration}}{\Delta t}
$$

Rule-Based Classification Approach
Define Rules
Use derived metrics to classify behaviours:

Accelerating: $\text{Acceleration} > \text{Threshold}$.
Braking: $\text{Acceleration} < -\text{Threshold}$.
Steady Speed: $|\text{Acceleration}| < \text{Small Threshold}$ and $|\text{Jerk}| < \text{Small Threshold}$.
Turning: $\text{Curvature} > \text{Curvature Threshold}$ or $|\theta| > \text{Angle Threshold}$.

Sliding Window Analysis
Analyse multiple time points to improve accuracy:

Smooth position/velocity data using moving averages.
Compute metrics like curvature and heading change over a 3–5 second window.

Combine Metrics for Robustness
Example pseudo-code for combining metrics:
if curvature > curvature_threshold and heading_change > angle_threshold:
    behaviour = "turning"
elif acceleration > acceleration_threshold:
    behaviour = "accelerating"
elif acceleration < -acceleration_threshold:
    behaviour = "braking"
else:
    behaviour = "steady"

Data Processing
Preprocessing

Smoothing: Apply moving averages or low-pass filters to reduce noise in position and velocity data.
Interpolation: Ensure consistent time intervals by interpolating data if timestamps are uneven.

Finite Difference Approximation
Estimate velocity and acceleration using numerical derivatives:

Velocity:
$$
  V_x(t) = \frac{x(t) - x(t-1)}{\Delta t}, \quad V_y(t) = \frac{y(t) - y(t-1)}{\Delta t}
  $$
Acceleration:
$$
  a_x(t) = \frac{V_x(t) - V_x(t-1)}{\Delta t}, \quad a_y(t) = \frac{V_y(t) - V_y(t-1)}{\Delta t}
  $$


I hope some of these ideas are useful !

Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I was able to achieve a good result thanks to your insights!
